# Mezuzah in the work place

Tags: halacha, blessing, gentiles, employment, mezuzah

If a Jewish person works in a 'non-Jewish' workplace (that he does not own) to what extent does he need to place a mezuzah on the doorposts of his personal/shared office and other building entrances? Regardless of whether others mind or not, is this Jew obligated or is it reshut?

If there are any cases where he would place a mezuzah, would he say a beracha if he was placing it on a doorpost that involves an area that isn't owned by him?

Comment: Please see [Shulchan Aruch, YD 286](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.286?lang=bi).

Answer (score 4):

He does not own or rent the space and has no legal or halachik right to it, therefore he is not obligated in a mezuzah. If he wanted to put one up, it could arguably be a problem since he might not be able to guarantee its respectful removal if he moved on from that job and forgot it there. (If he did, he would not make a bracha.)

Comment: As always, citing sources for your claims would be most valuable.

Comment: [This page from Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/225406/jewish/Which-Rooms-Require-a-Mezuzah.htm) says you might be obligated, but also cites no sources.  (They agree on not saying a b'racha.)

Comment: As a comment, a Jewish astronaut (Garrett Reisman) placed a mezuzah over his bunk in the International Space Station when he spent three months there.  Of course, the space station is not just a work place but is a residence as well.  I think he brought the mezuzah back with him when he returned to earth.

Answer (score 2):

I researched this as we are moving offices (in Israel - but for a global 'non-Jewish' corporation).

The practical halacha is that one places a mezuza in an office but without a blessing. Since an office is not a permanent dwelling in the same was as a house, there is a doubt if it absolutely requires one. On the other hand, since in our times, people spend significant periods of time in offices and eat there, it has certain characteristics of a dwelling. Thus the mezuza but without the blessing.

Specifically to be obligated in mezuza, a house needs to be a dwelling place - an office doesn't fully qualify ([Mishne Torah, Hilchot Mezuza, 6:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Tefillin,_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.6.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [SA YD 286:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.286.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) speaking of a store, see also Shulchan Haruch Harav [here](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/stores/) and [here](http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/office/))

Note an office where one sleeps might have a different law. [CYLOR](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

Addendum: I saw now that R Eliezer Melamed rules that one may say a blessing in a store or office if one eats there (Peninei Halacha Likutim vol. 1, Mezuza ch. 6)

> It seems that if the sellers are accustomed to eat there over the
>   course of the day, one may recite a *beracha* upon affixing the
>   *mezuza*.

Comment: you may be interested in this article from Tradition (Summer 1977) http://www.mesora.org/mezuza-gordon.pdf

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought this was an extremely interesting article and thank you very much for locating and sharing it. In many respects it reminds me of the monography R Slifin wrote on how the mitzva of shiluach haken evolved over time from a rationalistic to a mystical understanding (recommended reading if you haven’t done so)

Comment: @DoubleAA Re mezuza I think the battle between rationalistic and non-rationalistic can’t be expressed better than by the braita in Menachot 32b (cited on p. 21) where a misplaced mezuza is judged by Rashi to be a danger in terms of spirits attacking the house and R Tam thinks the danger is to hit one’s head on the mezuza and get hurt :-> !

Comment: Shkoyach Did you see the Arukh haShulchan I referenced, who argues that we don't rule like the Rambam you cite about it needing to be a dwelling place, and therefore Chanut is really obligated for us?

Answer (score 0):

If the Jew does not own it, he's not chayav, as it's not שעריך (See YD 286:1 where the whole conversation is about partnerships with Non-Jews).

The fact that it's an office seems to be secondary, and it's in general subject to Machaloket. So, if he's actually renting the office for more than a month and there's no sakana, then we can talk, (Yoreh Deah 286:23 only obligates a socher, not a shoel) but if he's just being allowed to use the space, Rav Moshe writes how he's not obligated. See Yoreh Deah 286:11, Taz and Pitchei Teshuva ad loc, Rav Pe'alim 2:YD:36, Iggerot Moshe Yoreh De'ah 1:178, and Yabia Omer 10 Yoreh Deah 58:28.