# Can you put a mezuzah on your office door after 30 days?

Tags: employment, mezuzah

When working as an employee outside Israel for a non-Jewish boss, is it possible to put up a mezuzah even after the initial 30 days of your job if you didn’t have the chance to do so because of your absence from the office in the first month?

Comment: related: [Mezuzah in the work place](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57565/mezuzah-in-the-work-place)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Patty-B and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I’ll try to broaden my question for re-opening it.

Comment: The rewrite is great. Problem is that this site doesn't answer personal questions. But if you follow the related question above you will notice that the "problem" is not whether it is too late after 30 days but rather whether or not you need a mezuza there in the first place. Someone who forgot to place a mezuza at home still has to/can place it even after 30 days. Best, for you, is to ask a Rav that you trust and who can ask further questions to clarify the case if needed